# How to I cast a type to a variable in an enum within a switch statement?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, switch-statement, pattern-matching

```swift
switch error {
case Project.Client.LoadError.operationFailed(let error2):
    switch error2 {
    case Project.Client.APIClientError.invalidStatusCode(let message, _):
        guard message != nil, message == "error" else {
            return refresh()
        }
        delegate?.error(invalidScript)
    default:
        refresh()
    }
default:
    refresh()
}
```

Here is my current code. This works but I feel there is a better way to do this.
How can I make `error2` NOT go through another `switch` statement and just cast it as an `invalidStatusCode` that I can use?

Or, what terms can I search up to better understand what is happening here/understand what to look up myself for the answer?
As I might not be fully understanding switch statements as casting type.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are just drilling down to one case for both switches, you don't need any switches at all. You can use `if case` instead. To generalize, suppose we have this:

```
enum Outer {
    case inner(Inner)
    case other
}

enum Inner {
    case message(String)
    case other
}
```

Now suppose `subject` might be an Outer. Then to determine that this is an Outer's `.inner` case whose Inner value is `.message` and that message's value is "howdy", we can say:

```
if case Outer.inner(let inner) = subject, 
    case Inner.message(let message) = inner, 
    message == "howdy" {
```

Comment: @Phillip A combination of both of our answers would be best here. Using a nested pattern to reduce the number of arbitrarily-named intermediate values (`error2`, `message`), and using `if case` instead of `switch` when there only needs to be two paths

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching of enums with associated values is composable, so you can do this:

```swift
switch error {
case Project.Client.LoadError.operationFailed(Project.Client.APIClientError.invalidStatusCode("error" , _)):
    delegate?.error(invalidScript)
default:
    refresh()
}
```

You might notice that this is a bit hard to read because of how long these fully-qualified type-names are.

I suspect the type of `error` is the general `Error`, but in other cases, if the type of `error` is already-known to be `Project.Client.LoadError`, then you can just use `.operationFailed` (leaving the type to be inferred from context). And if `.operationFailed`'s associated type is known to have type `Project.Client.APIClientError`, you can just use `.invalidStatusCode`.

If not, you can use some local type-aliases can help with that:

```swift
typealias LoadError = Project.Client.LoadError
typealias APIClientError = Project.Client.APIClientError

switch error {
case LoadError.operationFailed(APIClientError.invalidStatusCode("error", _)):
    delegate?.error(invalidScript)
default:
    refresh()
}
```

Comment: Pattern matching was the term I was looking for!
Thank you so much! And an extra thank you for helping me make it even cleaner.

Comment: If this satisfies your question, please vote on it and mark it as accepted :)